# Java Crit-bit Trees

Tags: java, collections, tree

Is there a built-in data structure in Java to represent a Crit-bit tree? Or any libraries available that might provide this functionality? I would also accept brief code as an answer, if one can be implemented in a simplistic brief way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try the [**radixtree**](http://code.google.com/p/radixtree/) java project?

You might find in it the structure you are looking for, like the:

- **RadixTree** class

(extract):

```
/**
 * This interface represent the operation of a radix tree. A radix tree,
 * Patricia trie/tree, or crit bit tree is a specialized set data structure
 * based on the trie that is used to store a set of strings. In contrast with a
 * regular trie, the edges of a Patricia trie are labelled with sequences of
 * characters rather than with single characters. These can be strings of
 * characters, bit strings such as integers or IP addresses, or generally
 * arbitrary sequences of objects in lexicographical order. Sometimes the names
 * radix tree and crit bit tree are only applied to trees storing integers and
 * Patricia trie is retained for more general inputs, but the structure works
 * the same way in all cases.
 * 
 * @author Tahseen Ur Rehman 
 * email: tahseen.ur.rehman {at.spam.me.not} gmail.com
 */
public interface RadixTree<T> {
    /**
     * Insert a new string key and its value to the tree.
     * 
     * @param key
     *            The string key of the object
     * @param value
     *            The value that need to be stored corresponding to the given
     *            key.
     * @throws DuplicateKeyException
     */
    public void insert(String key, T value) throws DuplicateKeyException;
```

- **RadixTreeNode** class

(extract):

```
/**
 * Represents a node of a Radix tree {@link RadixTreeImpl}
 * 
 * @author Tahseen Ur Rehman
 * @email tahseen.ur.rehman {at.spam.me.not} gmail.com
 * @param <T>
 */
class RadixTreeNode<T> {
    private String key;

    private List<RadixTreeNode<T>> childern;

    private boolean real;

    private T value;

    /**
     * intailize the fields with default values to avoid null reference checks
     * all over the places
     */
        public RadixTreeNode() {
        key = "";
        childern = new ArrayList<RadixTreeNode<T>>();
        real = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is rkapsi's [patricia-trie](https://github.com/rkapsi/patricia-trie), or if you're looking for something a little less complicated that you can hack on yourself, you can try his [simple-patricia-trie](https://github.com/rkapsi/simple-patricia-trie).

I've also got a [functional-critbit](https://github.com/jfager/functional-critbit) implementation available that's focused on space-efficiency (though its performance is fine, as well).  It comes in both mutable and immutable flavors.

Comment: '<T> T cast(Object o)' bothers mr. compiler.  Curious if you build using Eclipse? Eclipse's compiler lets you get away with things like that.

Comment: Yeah, eclipse sometimes bites me on that, but 0.0.4 up to the current head should compile fine with straight javac.  A cast method like that is a pretty common kludge for isolating unchecked cast warnings to one spot, and I've never had anything more than minor problems like [this one](https://github.com/jfager/functional-critbit/commit/6bbc21fee45b0bef9fff1eae1945c4eec35dc517) when I use it.  If you could open a github issue with more details about what you're seeing, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

try [concurrent-trees](https://code.google.com/p/concurrent-trees)

on gradle:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.concurrent-trees:concurrent-trees:2.4.0'
```